# Delete a Customer Programmatically

Tags: customer

How can I delete a customer in magento by refering using its object from `Mage::getModel("customer/customer")` ?

I already researched in google and with the bad luck I found nothing.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to delete the customer with some code that runs from the admin area, this should be enough:

```
$id = 5;//replace with desired id
//or
//$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($email);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
$customer->delete();
```

If you want to delete the customer from the frontend area you need to wrap the code above in this:

```
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
//code from above goes here
Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
```

Comment: thank you @marius but I do it on the backend =) thank you for the info =)

Comment: very helpful - especially the hint concerning the isSecureArea

Answer (score 7):

I find it out. customer is an EAV like products that can be deleted using `delete()` method.
Just flag the object to be deleteable using `$customer->setIsDeleteable(true)` because the customer model class which is `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` implements `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` which contains the `delete()` method

I used the following codes below

```
$customer->loadByEmail('test@test.com');
$customer->setIsDeleteable(true);
$customer->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get Customer By Id**

```
$id = 5;//replace with desired id
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
```

**Get Customer By Email**

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(0)->loadByEmail($email);
```

**Delete Customer**

```
$customer->delete();
```

Comment: in above link get customer by Email is not corrent, thats why I have to mentioned above line