# Delete All customer addresses where email is = email

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1!

I'm currently searching a way to programmatically delete a user/customer address where email is responding to the pointed one.

Take a look at my code:

```
<?PHP
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?PHP
$Timer = $_COOKIE["ConvertorTimer"];    
$Timer = $Timer + 1;    
setcookie("ConvertorTimer", $Timer, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

if($Timer <= 550){ ?>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<?PHP } ?>
</head>
<?PHP

    $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser = "user_convert";
    $dbpass = "mypass";
    $database = "mydb";

        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
        require_once $mageFilename;
        $app = Mage::app('default'); 
        Mage::app();


    function ConnectWithMySQLDatabase() {

        global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database, $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;

            $conres=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
            mysql_query('set names utf8', $conres);


        if (!$conres)
        {
          switch (mysql_errno())
          {
            case 1040:
            case 2002:
                if ($HTTP_SERVER_VARS[REQUEST_METHOD] == "GET")
                    die("<html><head><meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"20 $HTTP_SERVER_VARS[REQUEST_URI]\"></head><body><table border=0 width=100% height=100%><tr><td><h3 align=center>".ERR_SERVER_LOAD."</h3></td></tr></table></body></html>");
                else
                    die(ERR_CANT_CONNECT);
            default:
                die("[" . mysql_errno() . "] dbconn: mysql_connect: " . mysql_error());
          }
        }
        mysql_select_db($database)
            or die(ERR_CANT_OPEN_DB." $database - ".mysql_error());



    }

    ConnectWithMySQLDatabase();

                $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Customers` WHERE `CustomerPasswordHashMode`='1' AND `Converted`='0' ORDER BY `CustomerID` DESC LIMIT 1");


                while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
                {
                $CustomerID = addslashes($rowi['CustomerID']);
                $CustomerEmail = addslashes($rowi['CustomerEmail']);



                // So here i've got the email $CustomerEmail variable.
                // Now i want Magento to delete all addresses on customer which have the email $CustomerEmail
                // Simple SQL example which is not corresponding to the real Magento Structube but maybe will point
                // my idea better:
                // DELETE * FROM `Magento_Customer_Addresses` WHERE `CustomerEmail`='$CustomerEmail'
                // The example above is not answering to the real Magento Structure and the way Magento saves the addresses for it's customers.
                // I know that maybe i'll have to get the CustomerID's by the email and then delete the adressess by customer IDs but i don't know how;





                echo "$CustomerAddressFirstName $CustomerAddressLastName - Address has been deleted!!! Current Number of converting: $Timer<br>";
                }

?>
```

I've Used this code to convert accounts from Old system to the Magento Store:

```
<?PHP
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?PHP
$Timer = $_COOKIE["ConvertorTimer"];    
$Timer = $Timer + 1;    
setcookie("ConvertorTimer", $Timer, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

if($Timer <= 550){ ?>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<?PHP } ?>
</head>
<?PHP

    $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser = "user_convert";
    $dbpass = "mypass";
    $database = "mydb";

        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
        require_once $mageFilename;
        $app = Mage::app('default'); 
        Mage::app();


    function ConnectWithMySQLDatabase() {

        global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database, $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;

            $conres=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
            mysql_query('set names utf8', $conres);


        if (!$conres)
        {
          switch (mysql_errno())
          {
            case 1040:
            case 2002:
                if ($HTTP_SERVER_VARS[REQUEST_METHOD] == "GET")
                    die("<html><head><meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"20 $HTTP_SERVER_VARS[REQUEST_URI]\"></head><body><table border=0 width=100% height=100%><tr><td><h3 align=center>".ERR_SERVER_LOAD."</h3></td></tr></table></body></html>");
                else
                    die(ERR_CANT_CONNECT);
            default:
                die("[" . mysql_errno() . "] dbconn: mysql_connect: " . mysql_error());
          }
        }
        mysql_select_db($database)
            or die(ERR_CANT_OPEN_DB." $database - ".mysql_error());



    }

    ConnectWithMySQLDatabase();

                $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Customers` WHERE `CustomerPasswordHashMode`='1' AND `Converted`='0' ORDER BY `CustomerID` DESC LIMIT 1");


                while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
                {
                $CustomerID = addslashes($rowi['CustomerID']);
                $CustomerEmail = addslashes($rowi['CustomerEmail']);


                $v = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CustomerAddresses`  WHERE `CustomerAddressID`='$CustomerID' AND `CustomerAddressFirstName`!=''");
                $vrowi = mysql_fetch_array($v);



                $CustomerAddressFirstName = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressFirstName']);
                $CustomerAddressLastName = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressLastName']);
                $CustomerPassword = "$CustomerAddressFirstName-$CustomerAddressLastName-005";
                $CustomerAddressLine1 = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressLine1']);
                $CustomerAddressCity = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressCity']);
                $CustomerAddressPhone = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressPhone']);
                $CustomerAddressZip = addslashes($vrowi['$CustomerAddressZip']);

                $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
                $customer->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());

                $customer->setFirstname("$CustomerAddressFirstName");
                $customer->setLastname("$CustomerAddressLastName");
                $customer->setEmail("$CustomerEmail");
                $customer->setPasswordHash(md5("$CustomerPassword"));
                $customer->save();


                $address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
                // you need a customer object here, or simply the ID as a string.
                $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId());

                $address->setCountryId("BG"); //Country code here
                $address->setStreet("$CustomerAddressLine1");
                $address->setPostcode("$CustomerAddressZip");
                $address->setCity("$CustomerAddressCity");
                $address->setTelephone("$CustomerAddressPhone");

                $address->save();

                mysql_query("UPDATE `Customers` SET `Converted`='1' WHERE `CustomerID`='$CustomerID'");



                echo "$CustomerAddressFirstName $CustomerAddressLastName ID: <b>$CustomerID</b> - has been succesfully converted!!! Current Number of converting: $Timer<br>";
                }

?>
```

The problem with this convertor was the fact that it setted the address to customer by taking the address from the previously converted account but not from the account that it is actually converting now.

In another example, when it convert accounts with ids 1, 2, 3, it places the Adress of account `2` from account `1`, and it places the address for account `3` taking it from account `2` and so on.

Now i have to fix this mistake, if you have any other better idea i'll be glad to hear it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to the Magento install ? If you do, I would suggest including the app/Mage.php file and use this method to delete the customers using Magento instead of doing direct SQL call to the database: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16466/delete-a-customer-progmatically

Comment: Yes i do, but i don't want to delete the customer but only it's address or update the address with the correct one.

Comment: My bad I misread. I suggest you look into this post so you can update the addresses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172683/magento-how-to-update-shipping-address-using-customer-save-after-event

Comment: Thanks, but in this case i'll have to get the customer ID by `email`. I need that because i get the correct customer address from the OLD database by email and for the same email in the new database i'll have to set the correct address. So my question is how i can get the ID of account by email ? Thanks !

Comment: You can use the following code to load a customer by email: Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->loadByEmail("email@toload.com");

Comment: So by your advice my code must be working like this: http://pastebin.com/mt4eAgYD ? Please check it out and tell me if i'm loading the customer by email correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Slightly different as you don't need the observer part for your code, here is the version I would use (needs testing though): http://pastebin.com/ZPx4qujV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21636/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-digital-pianism).

Comment: Let's continue our discussion to chat because i have an error using the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how your loop should look like:

```
while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    $CustomerID = addslashes($rowi['CustomerID']);
    $CustomerEmail = addslashes($rowi['CustomerEmail']);


    $v = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `CustomerAddresses`  WHERE `CustomerAddressID`='$CustomerID' AND `CustomerAddressFirstName`!=''");
    $vrowi = mysql_fetch_array($v);



    $CustomerAddressFirstName = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressFirstName']);
    $CustomerAddressLastName = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressLastName']);
    $CustomerPassword = "$CustomerAddressFirstName-$CustomerAddressLastName-005";
    $CustomerAddressLine1 = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressLine1']);
    $CustomerAddressCity = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressCity']);
    $CustomerAddressPhone = addslashes($vrowi['CustomerAddressPhone']);
    $CustomerAddressZip = addslashes($vrowi['$CustomerAddressZip']);


    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->get‌​‌​Id())->loadByEmail($CustomerEmail);


    $dataShipping = array(
            'firstname'  => $CustomerAddressFirstName,
            'lastname'   => $CustomerAddressLastName,
            'street'     => array($CustomerAddressLine1),
            'city'       => $CustomerAddressCity,
            'region'     => '',
            'region_id'  => '',
            'postcode'   => $CustomerAddressZip,
            'country_id' => 'BG',
            'telephone'  => $CustomerAddressPhone,
    );

                                        $customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    if ($defaultShippingId = $customer->getDefaultShipping()){
             $customerAddress->load($defaultShippingId);
    } else {  
             $customerAddress
                    ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
             ;  

             $customer->addAddress($customerAddress);
    }            

    try {
            $customerAddress
                    ->addData($dataShipping)
                    ->save()
            ;          
    } catch(Exception $e){
            Mage::log('Address Save Error::' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE `Customers` SET `Converted`='1' WHERE `CustomerID`='$CustomerID'");



    echo "$CustomerAddressFirstName $CustomerAddressLastName With Adress: $CustomerAddressCity - $CustomerAddressLine1 - $CustomerAddressPhone ID: <b>$CustomerID</b> - has been succesfully converted!!! Current Number of converting: $Timer<br>";
}
```